# Issues trying to return multiple JSON results with Rails API/front-end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rails-api

I have an API with nonprofit information that I'm trying to get results out of based on the "category" parameter. Basically, I want to loop through and return the names, descriptions, address, phone numbers, and websites of each nonprofit under that category. I keep getting "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" errors or "undefined method []" errors with the approaches I've been taking. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Controller:

```
def index
   @homeless_organizations = Organization.get_homeless_organizations
end
```

Service

```
class Organization
  def self.get_homeless_organizations
   response = JSON.parse(RestClient.get('http://localhost:3001/organizations? 
   category=Homelessness'))
     response['name']['description']['address']['phone']['website'].each do   
     |response|
       puts response
       puts "#{response['name']['description']['address']['phone'] 
        ['website']}"
    end
  end
```

JSON body:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Transition Projects",
    "category": "Homelessness",
    "description": "Transition Projects delivers life-saving and life-changing assistance to some of Portland’s most vulnerable residents. Whether by helping a homeless veteran and her family find housing, sheltering hundreds of people each night with nowhere else to turn, or opening new pathways to employment, Transition Projects represents an invaluable part of Portland’s social fabric.",
    "address": "665 NW Hoyt St, Portland, OR 97209",
    "phone": "(503) 280-4700",
    "created_at": "2018-05-19T00:18:30.592Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-19T00:18:30.592Z",
    "website": "https://www.tprojects.org/"
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Portland Homeless Family Solutions",
    "category": "Homelessness",
    "description": "Giving hope to homeless families with children. Our mission is to empower homeless families with children to get back into housing - and stay there.",
    "address": "1221 SW Yamhill St #210, Portland, OR 97205",
    "phone": "(503) 915-8306",
    "created_at": "2018-05-19T00:18:30.600Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-19T00:18:30.600Z",
    "website": "http://pdxhfs.org/"
 },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Portland Rescue Mission",
    "category": "Homelessness",
    "description": "Food, shelter, clothing, mail service, restrooms, showers and other emergency services are available free of charge at Portland Rescue Mission's Burnside Shelter.",
    "address": "111 W Burnside St, Portland, OR 97209",
    "phone": "(503) 906-7690",
    "created_at": "2018-05-19T00:18:30.603Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-19T00:18:30.603Z",
    "website": "https://www.portlandrescuemission.org/.../food-shelter-services/"
 }
]
```

Comment: `response.each { |r| puts "#{r['name']} #{r['description']}" }`

Comment: You're "shadowing" the `response` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Once you parse the JSON response, you end up with an array of hashes. To get values out of all of the hashes, you need to loop through that array and call the [`Hash#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) method on each of the hashes for each of the values you want.

```
response.each do |organization|
  p [organizations['name'], organization['description']]
end
```

Since you need multiple values out of the hash, instead of calling them one at a time (as done above) you could make use of [`Hash#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) to do something similar to what it appears you were attempting and get all the values out at once, in a new array:

```
response.each do |organization|
  p organization.values_at('name', 'description')
end
```

As to what is wrong with your code:

Calling `response['name']` is calling the [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) which is different than the `Hash#[]`, it expects an integer index for which element you want access to, so if you only wanted to get the values from the first organization you could have done:

```
p [response[0]['name'], response[0]['description']]
```

But you passed it a string, which it was not expecting, so you got that `TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)`. (This is just an illustration, using `each` is better than passing specific indices, unless you only need specific indices.)

Finally, when you keep calling `#[]` one after the other like you're doing then, after the first one, you end up calling `#[]` on the return value of the previous call. In this case, if you had been calling `#[]` on a hash within the array and not the array itself, you'd end up calling [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), which is different than `Array#[]` and `Hash#[]`. Though it can take a string or an integer, it won't do what you want (if a string is given, it returns that string if it exists in the string you call `#[]` on; if an integer is given it returns the character at that position in the string):

```
# "Transition Projects" is `response[0]['name']`
"Transition Projects"['description'] # => nil
"Transition Projects"['Proj'] # => "Proj"
"Transition Projects"[8] # => "o"
```

and then you end up either calling `#[]` on `nil` (`NoMethodError`) or on another string.

Comment: Ah this worked! Thank you so much for the detailed answer, I definitely feel like I have a better overall understanding of the problem now.